# Kaguya s1 finale - What happens between fireworks and next semester?

Tags: kaguya-sama-love-is-war

Did Kaguya and Miyuki (Shirogane) really not talk at all from the scene in the taxi (except perhaps a 'Good night. See you next sem') or something?

Like from this point

> [image]

until this point

> [image]

In particular...Kaguya really does not even say thank you?

> [image]

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Well in the manga apparently it does go like this at least in the original 2016. But apparently to celebrate the 2019 live action adaptation (and the 2019 anime adaptation?), there was an additional chapter made set between chapters 45 and 46. (And apparently the anime doesn't use the bonus chapter?)

Fandom says

> This chapter was made to celebrate the release of the live action movie.

https://kaguyasama-wa-kokurasetai.fandom.com/wiki/Chapter_45-01

Seems basically it's

> Just more 'embarrassing'/'cool' things Miyuki says as if it were part of the end of the [Fireworks Arc](https://kaguyasama-wa-kokurasetai.fandom.com/wiki/Chapter_45-01) (because for some reason Chapter 46, also part of the s1 finale, isn't included in the Fireworks Arc?).

Anyway answer:

1. They do still talk. But Miyuki's still in 'I'm too genuinely focused to think about whether my words are embarrassing, cool or neither.'
2. I guess Kaguya really doesn't say thank you.